Context definition LangChain
I have a more general question on the definition of the context window within Langchain. I'm working with the library for a while now and have a good understanding of its usage and capabilities. However, what I still don't get is how does it explicitly define / access the context window.
If I look at a plain vanilla example (found in their tutorials), it looks like the content is loaded into the prompt itself:
template = """Use the following pieces of context to answer the question at the end.
If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't know, don't try to make up an answer.
Use three sentences maximum and keep the answer as concise as possible.
Always say "thanks for asking!" at the end of the answer.

{context}

Question: {question}

Helpful Answer:"""
custom_rag_prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template(template)

rag_chain = (
    {"context": retriever | format_docs, "question": RunnablePassthrough()}
    | custom_rag_prompt
    | llm
    | StrOutputParser()
)

rag_chain.invoke("What is Task Decomposition?")

How does it then get submitted to OpenAI that the larger context window applies? Is it as simple as just using {context} for declaration? Maybe I'm overthinking it or completely missing the point. But I was always asking myself how this works…any clarification appreciated.
